# Using ngAnimate with ng-show/ng-hide

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show, ng-hide

I have this html:

```
  <div ng-if="true">
    <div ng-show="hideMe">
      <div class="random" ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button ng-click="hideMe = false">hide</button>
  <button ng-click="hideMe = true">show</button>
```

And then I have this styling:

```
.random.ng-enter {
  transition: 2s ease all;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.random.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.random.ng-leave {
  transition: 10s ease all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.random.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

The template:

```
<p>a simple paragraph</p>

<div ng-repeat="user in info">
  {{user.nome}}

</div>
```

When I first load the page, the ng-enter-active works perfectly, but when I use the buttons Hide or Show the ng-enter and ng-leave don't work. 
Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Thank you :)

Here you have a plunker showing what I just exposed.

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/kNy30wKM9gA848k9ByPL?p=preview)

Comment: can you be more precise about your issue ? and it's good if you show us the content of template.html

Comment: I just added it. It's all in the plunker. Basically when I press Hide or Show I want it to assume de configurations I set on ng-leave and ng-enter

Comment: Don't forget to flag the answer as correct so the topic is closed ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit you html like this :

```
<div ng-if="true">
    <div ng-if="hideMe" class="random">
      <div  ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this should work.

The class **random** should be used with the element that show/hide and it should be with an ng-if

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did not know it needed to be in the same element with the ng-if